# Using file format constants when saving PowerPoint presentation with comtypes

Tags: python, powerpoint, comtypes

How do I access the constants available as file formats when saving a Powerpoint presentation through comtypes?

In the following example `32` is used as the format but I would like to use the constants listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff760025(v=office.14))) or at least find a documented list with value for each constant.

For Word there is this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat) that also contains the value for each constant.

```
import comtypes.client

powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pres = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(input_path)
pres.SaveAs(output_path, 32)
```

Comment: consider using python-pptx package

Comment: @AdamOstrožlík I need a package that works with the complete Office Suite and that can convert to all supported formats.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [How do I import a COM object namespace/enumeration in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1646230) (but using `comtypes` rather than `win32com`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access all enum names associated with the COM object you loaded via the `comtypes.client.Constants()` class; pass it the PowerPoint.Application COM object you created:

```
from comtypes.client import Constants, CreateObject

powerpoint = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pp_constants = Constants(powerpoint)

pres = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(input_path)
pres.SaveAs(output_path, pp_constants.ppSaveAsPDF)
```

The `Constants` instance loads the underlying Type Library and dynamically translates attribute lookups to typelib access. It is not included in the `comtypes` documentation for some obscure reason, even though [it was added nearly 10 years ago now](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/1d3d38b2a616674309e7eabe6b5c581042caf32a/CHANGES.txt#L320-L330).

Another option is to access the attributes on a generated module in the [generated type library](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#typelibraries), as [shown in the *Properties with arguments (named properties)* section](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#properties-with-arguments-named-properties). This would give you access to any of the constants associated with the Powerpoint IDL, including auto completion support IDEs (once generated by accessing the PowerPoint.Application object the first time around).

The module is generated automatically when you use `CreateObject()` if type information is exposed on the object that's being created; this is definitely the case for `'Powerpoint.Application'` as you don't set an interface explicitly. Automatic interface selection only works if there is type information available.

Enumeration names are added to the generated module at the top level, so directly use those:

```
import comtypes.client

powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

# only import the generated namespace after the com object has been created
# at least once. The generated module is cached for future runs.
from comtypes.gen import PowerPoint

pres = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(input_path)
pres.SaveAs(output_path, PowerPoint.ppSaveAsPDF)
```

The short name of the type library can be found in a VBA Object Browser; the screenshot in [Steve Rindsberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298640/100297) shows that for the `PpSaveAsFileType` enum that's `PowerPoint`. I believe the same name is also used in the [documentation for the `ppSaveAsFileType` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppsaveasfiletype); note the `(PowerPoint)` addition to the documentation title.

You can also use the GUID of the type library, plus version number, but that doesn't quite roll of the keyboard if you have to type that by hand.

You can use `from comtypes.gen import PowerPoint; help(PowerPoint)` to see what names have been defined if you need a reminder, or just reference the Microsoft documentation.

Either method avoids having to use magic numbers; the *type library definition itself* gives you the symbolic names.

If you find any code examples using `win32com` instead, then any use of `win32com.client.constants` attributes translates directly to `comtypes.client.Constant(...)` or `comtypes.gen.<module>` attributes.

---

<sub>I don't have access to a Windows setup to actually test any of this, I'm deducing information from reading documentation and the source code of `comtypes`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list from Microsoft which contains the values of each constant:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppsaveasfiletype

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a copy of PowerPoint, start it, press ALT+F11 to open the VBA editor, press F2 to open the Object Browser then search on SaveAs to get this list. Click on any constant name to see the value of the constant at the bottom of the dialog.

[image: SaveAs members]